# Using two topic's information in a subscriber's callback

Tags: ros, callback, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a design problem.

I have a topic with an image, that needs to be analyzed and I need to get a certain coordinate from it. I also have another topic with a certain coordinate.

I need to use both of those coordinates in a callback method. So let's say I have a subscriber's callback:

```
callback(imageInfo) {
    //I only get the imageinfo here
}
```

So I get the imageinfo there but I need to use the certain coordinate info also, to calculate a result.
I could create a global variable for the certain coordinate and have a different subscriber with a callback setting its value and then use the global variable in the callback(imageinfo).

But is there a better way? It doesn't seem that good.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207448/using-two-topic%27s-information-in-a-subscriber%27s-callback/) by [RosFan19](https://answers.ros.org/users/21450/rosfan19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2015-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

have a look at http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters

if your messages have Header fields with sync'ed time stamps you could use the TimeSynchronizer for instance:

http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Time_Synchronizer

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosFan19](https://answers.ros.org/users/21450/rosfan19/) on 2015-04-20**:
This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!